# Override jsf implentation in WAS

Tags: jsf, richfaces, websphere, overriding

I want to develop richface implented app on Ibm Websphere. I include *.jars under

WEB-INF/libs and  it runs succesfull. But first deployment proccess is realy terriable..

So I want to add libraries to server, not include in application.

(i belevie it could increase 1st deployment).. Is there a way to override server impelemented

JSf in server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the webapp's classloading policy to `module` instead of `application` in the Websphere deploy manager.